# how to fix "import win32api # noqa: E402 ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: %1 is not a valid"

Tags: python, pywinauto

import win32api
from pywinauto import application

app = application.Application
app.start("Notepad.exe")

Comment: This is the error message "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pywin.py", line 1, in <module>
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: %1 is not a valid Win32 application."

Comment: Usually I saw such issue when new Python installation was run upon previous version into the same folder. Please remove all Pythons and folders, do clean Python install and then clean `pip install pywinauto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is can be due to different bit versions of applications you are using here

refer:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGuHMVAruAE

so better to check the bit versions

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have only one version of python installed on my computer. "python 3.8 version" and Python launcher

Comment: no, you need to see if it is 32 bit or 64 bit, look in this - https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-basic-exercise-42.php, i searched and I think that pywin is 32 bit so you may need python 32 bit one